# Get unsolved array keys of product data tabs in woo product editor page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I can get array keys of product data tabs in woo product editor page by this code `var_dump( array_keys( $tabs ) );`, so I can hide them. But I could not solve the array keys of couple tabs that created by plugin and build in tab by the theme (flatsome). Any help really appreciate it. Thank you.

```
// Remove Product Type Tab Options
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs' , 'block_wc_product_tabs' );

function block_wc_product_tabs($tabs) {

      if (!current_user_can('yith_vendor')) {  // replace role ID with your own
          return $tabs;
      }

      var_dump( array_keys( $tabs ) );
      //unset($tabs['general']);
      //unset($tabs['inventory']);
      unset($tabs['linked_product']);
      unset( $tabs['tm_extra_product_options'] );
      //unset( $tabs['product_origin'] );

      return $tabs;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried a higher priority (-> later execution of your code) when adding the filter? `add_filter('woo..', 'block..', 99999);` e.g.

Comment: not yet, ok I am going try.

Comment: still no luck, the targeted array keys not showing up it just shows till string(24)

Comment: Sorry, haven't worked with these tabs before. Anyways, strictly speaking WooCommerce is off topic on this QA (as it is not core WP). You'll probably get answers more quickly on sites more focused on Woo